# How would I simplify this function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm learning about the function transformations, and was wondering how I would simplify this function: $$f(x)=7\left(\frac{-1}{6 (x-1)}\right)^2+1 $$

It includes both the base function and the transformation. Should I square everything in brackets, or multiply by brackets and then add?

Comment: Simon, I've added $\LaTeX$ to your question. Please check if the content is right.

Comment: Yes it's correct, thank you.

Comment: @Simon Fraser: Is your need to expand the terms? I don't know
exactly, what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$:

Do $\displaystyle\left(\frac{-1}{6(x-1)}\right)^2$ first, then multiply it with the $7$, then add it to $1$. Can you do it from here?

To your question, multiply comes after brackets and exponents. If you forget or is unsure, you can always check with some small number, i.e. $5\cdot3^2=5\cdot(3\cdot3)=5\cdot9=45$ but $5\cdot3^2\neq15^2=225.$

Answer (score 0):

You can use new variable instead of $x$.

Say  $$x=t+1$$
then
$$f(t+1)=\frac{7}{36 t^2}+1$$
Now set:
$$g(t)=\frac{7}{36 t^2}+1$$.

You've got a new function $g$ instead of $f$, which looks easier.
Now you may, if you wish write $t$ for $x$

$$g(x)=\frac{7}{36 x^2}+1$$

because $x$ is more used for variable-names.

In the old $f$ it was forbidden for $x$ to be $x=1$.
Now for our new $g$ we can't use $x=0$.